# Why getting a syntax error near unexpected token on running a shell script in Ubuntu?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ns2

I'm trying to run NS-2 simulation on Ubuntu OS.

To be honest, I'm new to Ubuntu OS and to batch files.

By typing:

```
bash bat.sh
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
bat.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `%%a'
'at.sh: line 1: `for /L %%a in (200,380,4000) do (
```

bat.sh:

```
for /L %%a in (200,380,4000) do (
ns lab5.tcl %%akb )
```

The second row is exactly what I want to do. I'm sending a variable of 200 kb, 580 kb and so on.

Running this batch file on windows works fine.

Comment: First, __batch__ is a term for scripts executed by command processor on Windows, MS DOS or IBM OS/2. Batch files are not supported on Linux. On Linux you have to write __shell__  scripts which require a completely different syntax than batch scripts on Windows. There are several shell interpreters on Linux: bash, sh, ksh, ... which also differ on syntax. You are using obviously __bash__. So when searching for commands for an Ubuntu shell script, include always the keyword __bash__ or __shell__ and never *batch*.

Comment: That would make things alot clearer. Though I've found a bash syntax over the internet and it still doesn't work..

Comment: Second,  on Windows text files have carriage return `\r` plus line-feed `\n` as line termination. On Linux text files have only `\n` as line termination. Shell scripts often do not work with lines terminated with `\r\n`. Use a text editor on Ubuntu for creating shell scripts which are saved by default with line-feed only as line terminator. In __Save As__ window it is usually possible to select the line termination type for an already created shell script with `\r\n` to save the file in __UNIX__ format. On using a Windows text editor, make sure to save in __UNIX__ format for shell scripts.

Comment: Thanks alot! It solved the problem with the code below (by emi)

Comment: Look in __Preferences__ of *gedit* for __EOL__ setting and make sure Unix (line-feed only) is selected. In __Save As__ window you should see also an __EOL__ (End Of Line) option. There is also the *gedit* plugin [Newline Madness](https://github.com/jefferyto/gedit-newline-madness) which might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your bash code is buggy. First, you might want to add the *hassbang/shebang* ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) ) at the very beginning of the file, so you don't need to specify the interpreter each time you run it and you can make this file executable with `chmod +x bat.sh`. Secondly, the syntax you use on the `for` is unknown to me ( http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html ). I'd rather write something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 200 380 4000
do
   ns lab5.tcl ${i}kb
done
```

Comment: Thanks alot!!

It seems the syntax is unknown because it's for windows...

I've tried your code and it gives the following error:

    bat.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'at.sh: line 4: `do

Tried to delete some carriage returns and now it gives:

    bat.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `ns'
'at.sh: line 3: `   ns lab5.tcl ${i}kb

 For the code:

    #!/bin/bash
    for i in 200 380 4000 do
       ns lab5.tcl ${i}kb
    done

P.S. I don't know why the <br/> doesn't work for my comment :(

Comment: In your example it seems you try to execute a command named `ns`, which I copied and corrected the variable reference. If it can't find it, you might want to add it to your `PATH` environment variable, call it with full path (`/full/path/to/ns ...`) or call it with local path (`./ns ...`).

Comment: I've already added the path for ns.. running 'ns lab.tcl 200kb' on the terminal works good.

Comment: Have you tried to put full path? I don't know how windows works exactly: maybe `ns` is a reserved word. Also note that this code needs to be written exactly like this. If you prefer to do it with less lines, you'll need semicolons: `for i in 200 380 4000; do ns lab5.tcl ${i}kb ; done;`.

Comment: Your code worked with Mofi's suggestion (changing the file type to linux instead of windows), Thanks alot!